# How to create ImageView pulse effect using nine old androids animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I wonder how I should create a pulse effect using nine olad androids framework animation.

To understand better lets say you have an ImageView and want to have a "pulse" effect like
make the image little smaller and then back to original size, scaling will be centered.

I use nine olad androids for backward compatibility.

Any other option is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`R.anim.pulse`:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />
```

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Animation pulse = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pulse);
imageView.startAnimation(pulse);
```

Comment: Did you try it? I tried it on Android 2.2 _without_ NineOldAndroids and it worked.

Comment: Using XML? I can't find to reference AnimationUtils class on nineoldandroids API. If you could do it, post how and I will mark as correct. I was ready to post a working solution using listeners. Nasty, but it worked for me. I need to do this with nineoldandroids. Is the API support such kind of animations previous 3.0?

Comment: You only need NineOldAndroids for early Android versions if you want to use animations that came with Android 3.0. Otherwise you can just use `AnimationUtils` that is available since Android 1.0. The animation I posted here is no Android 3.0 animation.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew that. Still don't know these difference netween SDK versions. Thank you. It works perfect then.

Comment: I don't think so but you can achieve that by using the first version of the XML I posted yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14217749/1 Increase the `startOffset` of the second animation.

Comment: Worked like a charm with some tweaking to my needs, thanx.

Comment: it's very simple and useful for me, thanks @MatthiasRobbers

Answer (score 17):

heart_pulse.xml
put heart_pulse.xml in res/anim folder
Add android:interpolator

then use in your activity like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"/>

ImageView imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Animation pulse = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.heart_pulse);
imageView.startAnimation(pulse);
```

Comment: How do I stop it?

Comment: @bonafernando use imageView.stopAnimation(pulse);

Answer (score 6):

to use @ Matthias Robbers solution directly from the XML, you can do the following:
create 2 files:

1- **pulse.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:toYScale="0.8"
        android:duration="500"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
</set>
```

**2- pulse_layout_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/pulse">
</layoutAnimation>
```

then in your layout xml file just add this animation to any view you need, for example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:src="@drawable/heart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/pulse_layout_animation" />
```