# Android: How to make a nice heartbeat animation?

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

This is my solution

anim/pulse.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="0.75"
    android:toYScale="0.75"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/bounce" />
<scale
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="1.25"
    android:toYScale="1.25"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/bounce" />
 </set>
```

then in activity.java:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pulse));
```

I'm not satisfied because a real beating heart has more elegant contractions. How could it be improved?

EDIT: I think that a fine effect would be something that imitate the heart beat. A fast contraction followed by another one. Maybe the last could be fast in the first half and then reverse slowly for the second half. Is there a way to make all these effects triggering each other?

Comment: A **real** beating heart is something **creepy** you wouldn't want to see...

Comment: What's your use case? a medical/sports application? a valentine's day app?

Comment: ok, I know :) it's only a simple effect to catch the eye of the user on a particular image

Comment: no, it's a game, there is an image I want to manipulate like a beating heart to communicate the message that it's vital to use it.

Comment: I don't need perfection, just wonder if it could be a better way, with more creativity

Comment: Its nice that you are trying to do something different. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14216798/3879470   it might be helpful...

Comment: Please.!!! This question shouldn't be closed...

Comment: You could use an animated GIF. Something like this: http://s386.photobucket.com/user/Snaazzy/media/gif.gif.html

Comment: it's not possible, gifs aren't supported

Comment: Who told you that? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7772170/2649012

Comment: once I tried and didn't work. However my problem is a little more complicated because if I'd want to animate an entire view group I couldn't do this way

Comment: Check out this link's: https://github.com/mharkus/Heartbeat-Monitor/blob/master/android/src/com/mlst/heartmonitor/Main.java pumpHeart() method and scaleUpListener. They have done a heart beat animation using `ViewPropertyAnimator`. Also can you show a sample of how your animation is working.